# (MacBook Late 2009) Bootcamp/Win 7: No device drivers were found

Tags: bootcamp, usb, windows, optical-drive

Recently I've been trying to install Windows 7 on my MacBook (Late 2009, macOS El Capitan, 10.11) using BootCamp.

However, when I'm about to install windows 7 it shows an error: "No device drivers were found", I've tried [using this](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL995?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) which are the drivers for the Late 2009 iMac, and even the drivers that are downloaded from BootCamp are also not detected, the Pen drive that I use is a 16gb USB 3.0 device.

I'm using a DVD to install Windows 7 Professional x64 with SP1.

Error Shown: Load driver: A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing. If you have a driver, floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.

Note: If the windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step

Comment: The link is for iMacs. You have a MacBook. If you are using the Boot Camp Assistant, then I assume you are installing Windows 7 by using a DVD. If this true? If not, then explain how you are able to do so without using DVD. Does your Windows 7 include SP1? Which version of macOS (OS X) are you using? Is Windows 7 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I'm using a DVD to install windows 7 Professional x64 with SP1 and I am currently using MacOs 10.11 (El Capitan).

Comment: @SteveChambers: 10.11 = Catalina?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, brain fart. I have fixed it.